# "FTP" client - new socket connection for downloading files?

Tags: java, sockets, ftp

I'm currently making my own "ftp" client and server in JavaFX.

I will try to describe my problem:

1. FTP client connects and applies username and password
2. If the credentials are valid, the server creates a new thread for the client which lets the client browse the folders and files. (Everything works fine here)
3. Now What i want to know is, if the client decides to download a file, does the client need to make a new connection to the server? Because I'm thinking that every download needs to be handled by a separate socket and a separate thread, is that correct? And the only way I can think of is to make a new connection and in the background apply the credentials again, and send the path of the file to download..

Is this even a good solution?

The server is using only one server socket. I'm not using any apache library or anything like that.

I would be grateful for all answers and ideas I could get.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because I'm thinking that every download needs to be handled by a separate socket and a separate thread, is that correct?

FTP needs a new connection for each data transfer, i.e. directory listings and file up- and download. This new connection means a different socket but does not mean in every case a new thread (there are ways to use multiple sockets within the same thread, details are out of scope of this question).

> ...apply the credentials again...

The credentials get not applied again. Instead client or server create a dynamic endpoint for the data connection and send the details to the peer. Only the data itself are exchange in this connection, that is everybody who manages to connect to the socket with the expected source address (and maybe source port) will be considered trusted.

For details about the protocol I recommend to study the standard, i.e. [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959).

Comment: Hi and thanks for a great and helpful answer! I'm just a little confused about the "endpoint"-thing, do you know if there is an example of that? I have searched very much but not found what I'm looking foor.

Comment: @Johan: The endpoint is where you connect to, i.e. the IP and port of a listener socket waiting for connections. I recommend you look at the PORT and PASV commands.

Comment: Yes but my server only uses one server socket for listening for clients. Am I supposed to use the same server socket for that too?

Comment: @Johan: You need multiple sockets. And I really recommend to read the standard or at least [this overview](http://www.ncftp.com/libncftp/doc/ftp_overview.html)

Comment: That text was a goldmine to read. This was exactly what I was looking for, now I know what to do! Thank you very much!